# Switch To the last mat-tab with if(){}

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-tab

i got 3 mat tabs and i want to open the third tab (Tab 3) with if(){} when enter the page. Is it possible ?

```
<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="center" style="width: 100%;" >
 <mat-tab label="Tab 1"></mat-tab>

 <mat-tab label="Tab 2"></mat-tab>

 <mat-tab label="Tab 3"></mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "selectedIndex" on mat-tab-group

example:

```html
<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="center" style="width: 100%;" [selectedIndex]="selectedTab">
 <mat-tab label="Tab 1"></mat-tab>

 <mat-tab label="Tab 2"></mat-tab>

 <mat-tab label="Tab 3"></mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

and in Typescript:

```js
selectedTab=0;
if(*/ condition */){
selectedTab= 2; */ tab number you want -1 */
}
```